# WP8 facebook deeplinking

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to make FB app open my application when user clicks specific link/post on someones wall ?  (Post/link should be posted by my FB app of course)

I know this is possible on Android/iOS, but is it possible on WP8 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from what i remember, you cant do this by posting a link, since it uses http protocol by default and not the custom protocol of your app by default(that is used of deeplinking).

However you can post a link to a page on your server, where you simply have to write a redirect javascript code and you can put your custom protocol URL there.

Let me know if you need me to elaborate a little more.

PS: All this is because, FB deosnt have a SDK for windows phone :(

Comment: Sounds promissing! Thanks!
I'll try that

Comment: I have tried it before. Let me know if it does/doesn't work out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have registered your protocol in the AppManifest.

```
<Extensions>
      <Protocol Name="my_protocol" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>
```

One way to do this is by posting custom urls using the Facebook SDK. Please note that the URLs that you post must not have http protocol.

So, you must specify an absolute URI with your own protocol in the links in your post.

For example, your post must have a link like,

my_protocol://openNewPage.xaml

And then you can handle this in your AssociationURI Mapper class.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're searching for:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx
```

Comment: How can FB app make such links for me ? Is this functionality implemented in it ? Your link is about OS functionality. I'm a more concerned about FB app support of such things. Thanks!